# Удаление большого числа QSharedPointer

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Всем привет!

В программе имеется большой массив измерений 5000 на 3000 точек. Каждая точка это структура данных передаваемая через QSharedPointer. Мне показалось что лучше всего будет так точки и хранить для отображения и обработки.

Но когда доходит дело до очистки массива все становится очень плохо, на удаление этого массива уходят десятки минут. В output я вижу список закрывающихся тридов. Я так понимаю что механизм удаления QSharedPointer идет в каких то отдельных потоках? Основной поток приложения тоже дико тормозит, хотя процессор загружен на 15% (удаляю элементы порциями), если разом то конца можно и не дождаться...

Как правильно удалять такие массивы QSharedPointer или идея хранить данные в таком виде изначальна утопична и надо было удалять шареды по мере поступления?

---

Переписал на обычные указатели, на первый взгляд работает быстрее, но все равно дико медленно. И тут я закрыл студию и запустил проект отдельно... Без студии оба варианта работают быстро, практически неразличимо.

И что это значит? Студия менеджерит работу с памятью и мешает? Или просто освободились ресурсы по памяти? Памяти вроде хватало. 
Почему создаются данные быстро, а удаляются медленно?

---

Причина чудовищного замедления - работа отладчика Студии даже для билда releas. В режиме без отладчика скорость работы с QSharedPointer и обычными указателями близки и оба достаточно быстры. Огромный выигрыш получается по памяти, QSharedPointer добавляют до 40% расхода памяти.

Comment: Попробуйте ради эксперимента использовать `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: это данные которые идут из других модулей и не очень прямыми путями, мне на std::shared_ptr долго переводить.

Comment: А зачем вообще shared? насколько они необходимы? Если размер массива известен заранее, как я понимаю, структура данных - скорее всего POD... Выделить память одним куском, потом точно так же куском освободить. А 8 миллионов раз обращаться к менеджеру памяти, да еще, скорее всего, не по одному разу (для данных, для счетчика) - так ли это необходимо?

Comment: Удаление `QSharedPointer` в любом случает требует выполнить ряд действий. Проверить количество ссылок на объект, удалить объект если это последний владелец, удалить счетчик ссылок. Плюс все это выполняется потокобезопасно, если мне не изменяет память, что тоже дает дополнительные расходы. Если ваши точки это не полиморфные типы, храните лучше их по значению.

Comment: Массив известен  на момент запуска программы. По ходу выполнения не меняется, но от запуска к запуску может быть изменен. В штатной работе он будет заполнен процентов на 80 да и то в конце, а в начале и при тестовых операция процентов на 10, не хочется сразу 1.5 ГБайта грохать. Shared взялся оттого что так измерения передаются между первыми этапами первичной обработки сигналами qt. Ну и да точки бывают разных видов, а передаются указателем базового класса :)

Comment: Ну тогда создайте массив указателей. А потом удаляйте содержимое чем-то вроде `qDeleteAll`. Если этот массив не владеет данными, на которые указывают указатели, то примените шаблон *виртуальный конструктор* для клонирования данных

Comment: Ну смотрите, но просто пытаться выгадывать по мелочи, не пытаясь изменить сам базовый принцип хранения, базовые алгоритмы - не лучший, а главное, обычно бессмысленный подход. Меня как-то обучила одна задача, когда у меня машина на работе на четвертый день счета завернула... а я дома переформулировал задачу и за 3 часа просчитал - очень отрезвило :) Вобщем, чем меньше вы обращаетесь к менеджеру памяти - тем лучше, чем меньше косвенности - тем лучше. И еще - 1.5 Гига делим на 8 миллионов - под 190 байт одно измерение?! У вас, наверное, очень большие накладные расходы памяти!

Comment: В моей концепции все было как раз стройно. Данные приходят с внешнего устройства, кладутся в память в виде структуры и указатель на них рассылается сигналом. Тут точно нужен QShared потому что приемников несколько. В итоге получается единая наполненная структура точки измерения. Ее дальше кидаем QSharedом и мне показалось логичным чтобы зря не копировать данные просто этот QShared и сохранить в финальном массиве. И кстати 5000х3000 = 15 000 000, а не 8. :)

Comment: Увы, непринципиально. Ну, 100 байт... Я тут поигрался - стандартный `shared_ptr<int>` тянет в качестве накладных расходов (кроме памяти для int'а) 16 байт памяти. При этом 10 миллионов таких указателей и создаются, и удаляются весьма шустро. Может, у вас какой-то деструктор слишком сложный?

Comment: На весь массив использование QSharedPointer добавляет ~300-400 МБайт на массив в 900-1000 МБайт данных. То есть под 40% накладных расходов сверху... Причина замедления 100% влияние студии, причем не отъедание памяти, а какие-то механизмы отладок, зачем-то она там следит что дико замедляет работу деструкторов.  Но накладные от использования shared значительны, хороший повод от них отказаться:)

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тому, что огромный набор экземпляров `QSharedPointer` ликвидируется единовременно, можно предположить, что удаление отдельных точек в процессе работы программы не производится. В этом случае неясно, какая польза от использования shared-указателей. По идее, подошли бы и обычные, не облачённые в какую-либо защитную форму.

В случае же, если приёмники сигналов с указателями имеют полномочия производить удаление полученных данных (полномочия по некоему условному соглашению, разумеется) или нет уверенности, что таковое не случится по невнимательности и хочется перестраховаться, то порекомендовал бы взглянуть в сторону `QSharedDataPointer`, который является более легковесным вариантом (достаточно сравнить исходники обоих типов указателей). Ко всему прочему, при помощи специальных флагов `QSharedDataPointer` может [оптимизированно](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO) использоваться как элемент в составе в других Qt-контейнеров.

Другая полумера может заключаться в том, чтобы передавать в конструктор `QSharedPointer` статическую функцию удаления, которая по факту не будет производить удаление данных, но будет перекладывать уже необременённые интеллектом указатели в отдельный список-контейнер. Далее останется только в нужный момент выполнить единовременную зачистку этого списка (может быть даже в отдельном потоке, если покажется, что тормозит):

```
static QList<Point*> pnts;

static void deletePoint(Point *pnt) {
    pnts << pnt;
}

static QList<QSharedPointer<Point>> ppnts;

void MyClass::function1() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        ppnts << QSharedPointer<Point>(new Point(), deletePoint);
    }
}

// ... later ...

void MyClass::function1() {
    qDeleteAll(pnts);
}
```

Но если подойти к вопросу решения проблемы иначе, то вероятнее всего всё же можно будет добиться куда лучшей участи, как по оверхеду на хранение умных указателей, так и по скорости ликвидации данных. Например, можно пересылать в сигналах не указатели на точки, а индексы или ключи единого контейнера. Соответственно, через некий, опять же единый, интерфейс можно по этим индексам или ключам получать доступ к данным.

Comment: Удаление всех точек - это частный случай, естественно по ходу работы есть удаление и некоторых областей и замена отдельных измерений. QSharedPointer использовал для рассылки в сигналах, чтобы приемники ненужные им точки игнорировали, и если точка не нужна в итоге никому она сама бы удалялась. Так же это упрощало варианты подмены данных в результате, просто заменяешь на новые, старые сами удаляются. Сейчас финальный массив переписан на обычные указатели. Спасибо за идеи реализации.